# why it is always fail that saved NSArray in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to save `NSArray` ,  but it is fail, why?

```
 -(void)SaveDataAll:(NSMutableArray *)dataToSave:(NSString *)name
    {  
            NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:dataToSave];


            // save path
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);

            if ([paths count] > 0)
            {
                // Array path
                NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

                NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   array====%@",array);
                 NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   dataToSave====%@",dataToSave);  
                // save array
                [array writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];

                // getout
                NSArray *arrayFromFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayPath];

                NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   ====%@",arrayFromFile);  
            }
    }
```

this is printed array.

```
2013-01-22 16:51:45.010 [49227:c07] SaveDataAll   array====(
    "\U4ee5\U8272\U5217\U548c\U4f0a\U6717\Uff1a\U4e00\U500b\U611b\U60c5\U6545\U4e8b\Uff1f",
    "\U53f2\U63d0\U82ac\Uff0e\U611b\U5ef8\U65af: \U4e00\U500b\U7236\U89aa\U8207\U5973\U5152\U7684\U9023\U7e6b\Uff0c\U4e00\U6b21\U4e00\U5f35\U7167\U7247",
    "Molly Crockett \U8ac7\U5c0f\U5fc3\U300c\U795e\U7d93\U80e1\U8aaa\U300d",
    "Maz Jobrani: \U7576\U4e00\U500b\U6c99\U70cf\U5730\U963f\U62c9\U4f2f\U4eba\U3001\U5370\U5ea6\U4eba\U3001\U548c\U4f0a\U6717\U4eba\U8d70\U9032\U5361\U9054\U7684\U9152\U5427....",
    "Ellen 't Hoen: \U85e5\U7269\U5c08\U5229\U806f\U76df\Uff0c\U62ef\U6551\U751f\U547d",
    "Nina Tandon\Uff1a \U7d44\U7e54\U5de5\U7a0b\U5b78\U662f\U91ab\U7642\U500b\U4eba\U5316\U7684\U9060\U666f?",
    "\U5091\U592b\Uff0e\U53f2\U5bc6\U65af\Uff1a\U5f9e\U76e3\U7344\U5b78\U5230\U7684\U7d93\U5546\U4e4b\U9053",
    "Bobby Ghosh: \U70ba\U4f55\U5168\U7403\U8056\U6230\U5df2\U7d93\U8f38\U4e86",
    "\U4fdd\U7f85\U00b7\U5361\U8fea\U5c3c\Uff08Paolo Cardini\Uff09\Uff1a \U5225\U518d\U4e00\U5fc3\U591a\U7528\U4e86\Uff01\U8a66\U8a66\U5c08\U5fc3\U4e00\U81f4\U5427\Uff01",
    "Munir Virani: \U6211\U5982\U4f55\U611b\U4e0a\U79bf\U9df9",
    "\U73cd\U59ae\Uff0e\U96ea\U666e\Uff1a\U7834\U788e\U7684\U8eab\U9ad4\U4e0d\U4ee3\U8868\U7834\U788e\U7684\U4eba",
    "Ernesto Sirolli: \U60f3\U8981\U5e6b\U52a9\U4eba\U55ce? \U9589\U4e0a\U5634\Uff0c\U7136\U5f8c\U807d\U5427!",
    "14:57",
    "03:38",
    "11:18",
    "07:11",
    "11:16",
    "06:19",
    "05:00",
    "16:31",
    "02:52",
    "06:41",
    "18:57",
    "17:09",
    "14:57",
    "03:38",
    "11:18",
    "07:11",
    "11:16",
    "06:19",
    "05:00",
    "16:31",
    "02:52",
    "06:41",
    "18:57",
    "17:09",
    "<UIImage: 0x95075d0>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa297da0>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa29c480>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa27bae0>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa29b5c0>",
    "<UIImage: 0x950c0d0>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa29fcb0>",
    "<UIImage: 0x950cee0>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa2a0310>",
    "<UIImage: 0x9509310>",
    "<UIImage: 0x95509a0>",
    "<UIImage: 0xa297fe0>",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/israel_and_iran_a_love_story.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/steven_addis_a_father_daughter_bond_one_photo_at_a_time.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/molly_crockett_beware_neuro_bunk.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/maz_jobrani_a_saudi_an_indian_and_an_iranian_walk_into_a_qatari_bar.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/ellen_t_hoen_pool_medical_patents_save_lives.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/nina_tandon_could_tissue_engineering_mean_personalized_medicine.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/jeff_smith_lessons_in_business_from_prison.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/bobby_ghosh_why_global_jihad_is_losing.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/paolo_cardini_forget_multitasking_try_monotasking.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/munir_virani_why_i_love_vultures.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/janine_shepherd_a_broken_body_isn_t_a_broken_person.html",
    "/talks/lang/zh-tw/ernesto_sirolli_want_to_help_someone_shut_up_and_listen.html"
)
```

but `NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   ====%@",arrayFromFile);`   arrayFromFile always is nil?

Comment: try to print the arrayPath and see if you get a valid location.

Comment: does -[NSArray writeToFile: atomically:] returns YES?

Comment: Please don't name your methods like that! It makes it harder to maintain and use. EDIT: I typed what vshall and GameBit beat me to, so please share that information.

Comment: does -[NSArray writeToFile: atomically:] returns true? – GameBit just now---------------return true

Comment: try to print the arrayPath and see if you get a valid location.------------------ arrayPath====/Users/jinpeng/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/9C4E4BC7-B41C-45B3-81B4-3DB972AFAE60/Documents/tedhelper

Comment: try to print the arrayPath and see if you get a valid location.------------should be ok,   because     NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"test",  nil];   this function run , arrayFromFile  get the  @"test".

Comment: Why do you copy `dataToSave` to another array? Please use `NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   dataToSave====%@",[dataToSave description]);` to show the content.

Answer (score 2):

You have UIImage in array - they can't be saved

Answer (score 2):

your array have images also. so you can not directly save into your location.
so you have to convert NSArray as NSData format. and the store that data into your location.

```
NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourarrayName];
                [data writeToFile:yourfullpath atomically:YES];
```

like wise while to retrieve the file use following code.

```
NSData *NewData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:yourfullpath];
NSArray *arrayNew=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:NewData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RolandasR

Because of `UIImage` in array - they can't be saved

This is one easy way, solve this question by----" archivedDataWithRootObject"-------can get the root object of array.

> -(void)SaveDataAll :(NSMutableArray *)dataToSave:(NSString *)name {
>
> ```
> [self  Save_str:dataToSave:name];
>  }
> ```
>
> -(void)Save_str:(NSMutableArray *)dataToSave1:(NSString *)name {
>
> ```
> // -(void)SaveData:(NSInteger)rowChoice
> {
>
>
>
>     //change from nsmutalblearray to nsarray
>     NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:dataToSave1];
>
>     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
>                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
>
>     if ([paths count] > 0)
>     {
>         // Array的保存路径
>         NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
>                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
>
>
>         NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
>
>
>         bool saveok=[data writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];
>
>         if (saveok) {
>             NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   saveok====true");
>
>         }
>         else{
>             NSLog(@"SaveDataAll   saveok====false");
>         }
>
>     }
>
> }
>  }
> ```